# Issue with authorization twitter (devise gem, rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, twitter, devise

Good day. Maybe my problem is nonsense but i have after singup in twitter error:

ArgumentError in Devise::RegistrationsController#new

wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)

I use multiply singup in my app and other work good

My callback controller:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: %i[google_oauth2 twitter github]

  def self.from_omniauth(auth, _signed_in_resource = nil)
    user = User.where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first
    if user.present?
      user
    else
      user_with_email = User.find_by_email(auth.info.email)
      if user_with_email.present?
        user = user_with_email
      else
        user = User.new

        if auth.provider == 'github'

          user.provider = auth['provider']
          user.uid = auth['uid']

          user.oauth_user_name = auth['info']['name']
          user.email = auth['info']['email']
          user.save

        elsif auth.provider == 'twitter'

          user.provider = auth.provider
          user.uid = auth.uid
          user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token

          user.oauth_expires_at = auth.extra.raw_info.name


        elsif auth.provider == 'google_oauth2'

          user.provider = auth.provider
          user.uid = auth.uid
          user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token

          user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
          user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
          user.email = auth.info.email
          user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
          user.save
        end
      end
    end
    user
  end

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    if session['devise.user_attributes']
      new(session['devise.user_attributes'], without_protection: true) do |user|
        user.attributes = params
        user.valid?
      end
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def password_required?
    super && provider.blank?
  end
end
```

Thank you for attention and help.

Comment: What's the full error message, and your RegistrationsController?

Comment: @SebastianPalma RegistrationsController from devise gem and error
https://ibb.co/bwOJGn

Comment: What Rails version are you using?

Comment: @SebastianPalma Rails 5.1.5

Comment: Try removing the `without_protection: true` option, it has been removed since rails 4. And also it seems you need a `tap` before opening that block?

Comment: @SebastianPalma that helped but now i have blank email, it's because twitter doesn't give email user i suppose so?

Comment: Check on your params what's the value they're handling.

Comment: You can ask for emails from twitter. Check here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/manage-account-settings/api-reference/get-account-verify_credentials

Comment: Ok i think i need to configure my twitter application, i will try thank.